# Different toggle functions in a javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function mobile_menu() {
    if (document.getElementById('mobile_menu').style.display == "none") {
        document.getElementById('mobile_menu').style.display = "block";
        return;
    }
    if (document.getElementById('mobile_menu').style.display == "block") {
        document.getElementById('mobile_menu').style.display = "none";
        return;
    }
}

function main_menu() {
    if (document.getElementById('main_menu').style.display == "none") {
        document.getElementById('main_menu').style.display = "block";
        return;
    }
    if (document.getElementById('main_menu').style.display == "block") {
        document.getElementById('main_menu').style.display = "none";
        return;
    }
}
```

```html
<div onclick="mobile_menu();">Open Mobile Menu</div>
<ul id="mobile_menu" style="display:none;">
  <li>Menu 1</li>
  <li>Menu 2</li>
</ul>
<div onclick="main_menu();">Open Main Menu</div>
<ul id="main_menu" style="display:none;">
  <li>Menu 1</li>
  <li>Menu 2</li>
</ul>
```

How can I write both javascript in one function?
Ex: I want to just write onclick="open_close();" to any div and add just id of div which want to open and close to javascript function.

May you help me?

Comment: Make the part that is variable (the ID) a **parameter** of the function. Learn more about functions: http://eloquentjavascript.net/03_functions.html .

Comment: Pass as argument to your handler function the ID you want to target. But you shouldn't use inline script, use unobstrusive javaascript to bind event. Now just wondering why do you tag question with `jQuery`? You are obviously not using it

Comment: do you want to toggle the other `ul` or the next `ul` on click of its caption `div`?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/owz37d2m/

Comment: John R - Thank you for your answer. It is working perfect!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show hide the menu on page load then what I would suggest you is to use Media Queries to toggle the mobile menu and the main menu depending on the screen size.

If you still want to use Javascript then I'd change it to something like this.

### HTML

```
<div class="toggle" data-id="mobile_menu">Open Mobile Menu</div>
<ul id="mobile_menu" style="display:none;">
    <li>Menu 1</li>
    <li>Menu 2</li>
</ul>
<div class="toggle" data-id="main_menu">Open Main Menu</div>
<ul id="main_menu" style="display:none;">
    <li>Menu 1</li>
    <li>Menu 2</li>
</ul>
```

### Javascript

```
$(".toggle").click(function() {
    var _id = $(this).data("id");
    $("#" + _id).toggle();
});
```

**Changes:** Setting `data-id` attribule on the `div` equal to the `id` of the `ul` which you want to toggle, giving class to the `div` so event can be triggered easily.

Answer (score 0):

write a function `toggleDiv`

```
function toggleDiv(divId) {
    if (document.getElementById(divId).style.display == "none") {
        document.getElementById(divId).style.display = "block";
    }
    else if (document.getElementById(divId).style.display == "block") {
        document.getElementById(divId).style.display = "none";
    }
}
```